# Simplify the inequality $2<\frac{10}{x}<3$ to an inequality for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, self-learning, fractions

I'm not sure what to google search for this.  Let's say I have the expression:

$$ 2 < \frac{10}{x} < 3 $$

We need to see if x is positive or negative.  If positive, we have:

$$ 2x < 10 < 3x $$

If negative we have:

$$ 2x > 10 > 3x $$

It can't be negative since $2x$ can't be greater than $10$.  So $x$ must be positive.

Now, what do I do with $ 2x < 10 < 3x $ to get $x$ in the middle so that it is $x$ not $1/x$.  I am not sure what rule or term to google for.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that if $10/x$ is between two positive numbers ($2$ and $3$) $x$ can't be negative, for otherwise $10/x$ is negative.

Comment: Yeah just saw that, I'm just trying to follow the rules.

Comment: So, $10/3 \lt x \lt 5$

Comment: To get $x$ in the middle, you read the two last inequalities separately. You get $x>10/3$ and $x<5$, or $10/3<x<5$

Comment: Ok so you split the inequality into two, then put it back together. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to prove that if $a,b$ are positive and $a < b$ then $\frac 1a > \frac 1b$.  Once you prove that then $2 < \frac {10}x < 3$ would imply $\frac 12 > \frac x{10} > \frac 13$.

Comment: Or just to be different:  $2x <10 < 3x$ means both $x < 5< \frac 32x$ and $\frac 23 x < \frac{10}3 <x$.  So $\frac 23 x < \frac {10}3 < x < 5 < \frac 32x$ so zooming in on a microscope:  $\frac {10}3 < x < 5$.

Comment: Or;   $2x < 10 < 3x$.  Multiply everything by $2$ to get $4x <20 < 6x$ and multiply everything by $3$ to get $6x < 30 < 9x$.  So $20 < 6x < 30$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the inequality $2x<10<3x$ is actually two inequalities:
$$2x<10\qquad\text{ and }\qquad 3x>10.$$
Dividing them by $2$ and $3$, respectively, shows that
$$x<\frac{10}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x>\frac{10}{3},$$
which can be written more concisely as $\tfrac{10}{3}<x<\tfrac{10}{2}.$

---

More abstractly, for the function $f(x)=\tfrac1x$ we can write the inequalities as
$$f(\tfrac12)<f(\tfrac{x}{10})<f(\tfrac13).$$
Because $f(x)$ is positive if and only if $x$ is positive, we see that also $\tfrac{x}{10}$ is positive, so $x$ is positive. Moreover, because $f$ is strictly decreasing on the positive numbers, it follows that
$$\tfrac12>\tfrac{x}{10}>\tfrac13,$$
yielding the bounds $\tfrac{10}{3}<x<\tfrac{10}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{10}x>0 \implies x>0$$

then

$$2 < \frac{10}{x} < 3 \iff 2x<10 \quad \land \quad3x>10 $$

that is

$$ x<5 \quad \land \quad x>\frac{10}3 $$

or $x\in \left(\frac{10}3,5\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x$ can't be negative since then $10/x$ will be negative and won't lie between $2,3$. You have to inequalities $2x<10$ and $10<3x$ and you are looking for values of $x$ such that both inequalities are satisfied simultaneously. The first gives $x<5$, the second gives $x>10/3$ and since you require $x$ to satisfy both, you take the common values in these two ranges i.e. $\frac{10}3<x<5$.

Answer (score 1):

Break it into two problems.

You have $2 < \frac{10} x$ and $x > 0$.

So $2x < 10$ and $x < 5$.

ANd you have $\frac {10}x < 3$ so $10 < 3x$ and $x > \frac {10}3$.

So $\frac {10}3 < x < 5$.

.....

Actually if we know for positive numbers that if $a < b$ then $\frac 1b < \frac 1a$ (which is *easy* to prove if you can't take it for a given) we can do this in one fell swoop:

$2 < \frac {10}x < 3 \implies$

$\frac 12 > \frac x{10} > \frac 13\implies $

$10\frac 12 > x > 10\frac 13 \implies$

$\frac {10}3 < x < 5$.

Comment: +1, beated me ...

Answer (score -1):

Solution without cases.

We need to solve $$\frac{10-3x}{x}<0$$ and $$\frac{2x-10}{x}<0,$$ which gives
$$x\in(-\infty,0)\cup\left(\frac{10}{3},+\infty\right)$$ and $$x\in(0,5),$$ which gives the answer:$$\left(\frac{10}{3},5\right).$$